# How do I programmatically copy an existing Field to another Entity?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I want to add two new fields to the Commerce Discount entity --- an image and a long text. And I want these to be visible through Views.

I was going to use this code to add the fields:

http://www.monarchdigital.com/blog/2013-08-09/programmatically-creating-fields-drupal-7

But, I was thinking that there are already two fields attached to Node Bundles that do exactly what I want. All I really need to do is -copy- that field information to the Commerce Discount entity Bundles.

So I was thinking that this might do the trick, but I'm not

`function() my_module_update_7000() {
  // copy field info from existing entity
  $field_name = 'field_page_banner';
  $field = field_info_field($field_name)
  field_create_field($field);`

// copy field instance from existing entity
  $field_instance = field_info_instance('node', 'field_page_banner', 'page')

// ???? will this screw up the data in any existing bundles?
  $field_instance['entity_type'] = 'commerce_discount',
  $field_instance['bundle'] = array('order_discount', 'product_discount'),

field_create_instance($field_instance);
}

1. Can someone look at this and let me know if I'm on the right track here? I'm not clear on how to assign the field to the new Bundle without 'un-assigning' it from the existing Bundles (if that makes sense.)
2. Is there anything else I need to do to make these fields available to add to existing Views?
3. Is there anything else I need to do to make these fields available to users when editing Commerce Discounts?

Comment: In regard to #1, that's kind of the point of field instances--to be able to reuse fields on different entities and bundles. So if you have an existing field, you don't have to recreate it. Just use field_create_instance and you have described above. You're not unassigning the existing field instance(s) unless you explicitly delete it from the entity and/or bundle.

Comment: Got it. If I may ask a follow up... what is it in the Entity that determines whether or not one can add/edit fields from the Admin interface?

Comment: I believe by default, there are no restrictions on fields. Take a look at the Field Permissions module if you need something to do that.

Comment: @jchwebdev there's also the `'fieldable'` key on the `$entity` info "Set to TRUE if you want your entity type to accept fields being attached to it." https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7

Comment: @DavidThomas I looked in the Entities under Devel and it -says- that the entity type 'Commerce Discounts' has a key called 'fieldable' and it is set to TRUE. But in the Commerce Discounts Admin there was no way to add a new -field-. So there must be something else to it. Anyhoo, your suggestion got me to where I could add programmatically. I just wish I could understand the mechanism that allows one to add fields via Admin (for the future.)

Comment: @jchwebdev, for a module to enable the field UI, it needs to be fieldable and it also needs to define valid `'admin'` menu paths, e.g: in `hook_entity_info` or `hook_entity_info_alter` See: `node_entity_info` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_entity_info/7

Comment: Please note, if you are gleaning your bundle name from the `admin/structure/types` page, hyphens in bundle names should be replaced with underscores. So if your bundle name is `page-custom` when you hover over the `edit` link, you'll need to change it to `page_custom` in the `bundle` array key in `field_create_instance()` array argument.